# Java JPA - How PUT an object with a list and update the list objects as well with CRUD?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, crud

I have an object that contains a list of other objects that I cannot seem to get to update correctly.  I can create object(Product) with the list of objects(ProductItemQuantity) no problem. I can also do a PUT with the list of objects, but it creates a new list of objects everything I do a PUT.  I want the list of objects I provide to be updated instead of having it create a new list every time I do a put of the parent object.

If I add an ID to the ProductItemQuantity, I get an exception:

```
detached entity passed to persist
```

Here are my classes:

**Product.java**

```
    @Entity 
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    private Organization org;
    private String barCode;
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
    private Status status;
    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
    private List<Fee> fees;
    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Note> notes;
    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ProductItemQuantity> productItems;
    private Integer stock;
    private BigDecimal msrp;
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime createdOn;
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime updatedOn;

    // Getter & Setters
```

**ProductItemQuantity.java**

```
@Entity 
public class ProductItemQuantity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private Long id;
    private Integer count;
    @ManyToOne
    private ProductItem productItem;
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime createdOn;
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime updatedOn;

// Getters / setters
```

**ProductItem.java**

```
@Entity 
public class ProductItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    private Organization org;
    @ManyToOne
    private Supplier supplier;
    private String barCode;
    private String description;
    private String name;
    private Integer stock;
    private Integer caseQty;
    private BigDecimal caseCost;
    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Note> notes;
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime createdOn;
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime updatedOn;
```

**ProductController.java**

```
@PutMapping("/{id}")
public Product update(@RequestBody Product product, @PathVariable long id) {


    Product savedProduct = productService.save(product);


    return savedProduct;
}
```

**Working CRUD PUT request: http://localhost:8080/product/1**

```
{
    "barcode":"12347163",
    "name":"Product 1",
    "stock": 12,
    "msrp": 29.99,
    "org": {
        "id":1
    },
    "status":{
        "id":1
    },
    "productItems":[{
        "count":30
    },{
        "count":30
    }
        ],
        "fees":[{
            "id":1

        },{
            "id":2

        }],
    "notes":[{
        "title":"Product Created",
        "description":"Note created by user X on 12/16/2019 11:00PM"
    },{
        "title":"Product Updated",
        "description":"Product updated stock by user X on 12/16/2019 11:00PM"
    }]
}
```

**Broken CRUD PUT request: http://localhost:8080/product/1**

```
{
    "barcode":"12347163",
    "name":"Product 1",
    "stock": 12,
    "msrp": 29.99,
    "org": {
        "id":1
    },
    "status":{
        "id":1
    },
    "productItems":[{
        "id":1,
        "count":30
    },{
        "id":2,
        "count":30
    }
        ],
        "fees":[{
            "id":1

        },{
            "id":2

        }],
    "notes":[{
        "title":"Product Created",
        "description":"Note created by user X on 12/16/2019 11:00PM"
    },{
        "title":"Product Updated",
        "description":"Product updated stock by user X on 12/16/2019 11:00PM"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to update the property to this:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"}) 
private List<ProductItemQuantity> productItemQuantities;
```

And then set it manually in the put

```
    List<ProductItemQuantity> piqs = product.getProductItemQuantities();

    if (piqs != null) {
        List<ProductItemQuantity> piiList = new ArrayList<ProductItemQuantity>();
        for (ProductItemQuantity pii : piqs) {
            // Check for ID in here?
            ProductItemQuantity curPII = piqService.getOne(pii.getId());
            curPII.setCount(pii.getCount());
            piiList.add(curPII);
        }
        originalProduct.setProductItemQuantities(piiList);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your objects are detached because the relations (OneToMany, ManyToMany) is set only from one direction. In order to persist them, you must set the relationship bidirectional. Your relation is unidirectional, because the parser (jackson) will make the following objects:

```
Product product = new Product();
Fee fee = new Fee();
fee.setId(1);
product.setFees(Arrays.asList(fee));
```

In a bidirectional relationship, both sides must be set :

```
product.getFees().forEach(fee-> fee.getProducts().add(product));
```

It is a good practice to keep separated the persistence object from the controller object, because the persistence object deals with relationships as well.

From my experience, if you want to use GeneratedValue, you have first to select the entity from the database and after to modify it. Does not make much sense to create a new object and set the id on it, if you expect hibernate to generate it.

So, you may need to do a select first :

List fees = // select all fees with id in the product fee list

and after:

```
product.setFees(fees);
fees.forEach(fee -> fee.getProducts().add(product));
```

Your method is a PUT, so you should not save directly the product object (it will create a new entry in the database).

```
@PutMapping("/{id}")
public Product update(@RequestBody Product product, @PathVariable long id) {
    Optional<Product> originalProductOptional = productRepository.findById(id);
    // you should add a check here : if originalProduct is not found, return 404
    Product originalProduct = originalProductOptional.get();
    originalProduct.setName(product.getName());
    // here update all fields and relations

    productRepository.save(originalProduct);
    return originalProduct;
 }
```

Comment: The thing I don't get is that it was not creating a new Product every time I sent the request.  It was updating the product correctly unless I sent the productItems along with the request.  It would only fail when I sent productItems to update.